# getting garbage values while accessing elements in mat in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Hi I have a matrix declared as rgbMat and I am trying to rotate it by the following code:

```
    CvMat* rot = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_32FC1);
    CvPoint2D32f center = cvPoint2D32f(rgbMat->width/2,rgbMat->height/2); 
    double angle = 90;
    double scale = 1;
    CvMat* rot3= cv2DRotationMatrix( center, angle, scale, rot);
```

Unfortunately, I am getting only 6 values as output whereas, I was expecting 25 values, as my original rgbMat is 5*5 matrix as shown below:

```
       {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} ,
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} ,
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ,
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}  }
```

Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, stick with either the C API (CvMat*, cvFoo) or C++ API(Mat, Foo). With that cleared, you do get a correct rotation matrix, now you have to **apply it** using either cvWarpAffine or WarpAffine.

Answer (score 2):

You are only getting 6 values output because you are iterating over and printing the values of your rotation matrix, **not** the values in `rgbMat`. The code that does this is in fact correct, and you are getting the output you should.

In addition to Boyko Perfanov's suggestions, which I advise you to follow, you can also use [`cvTranspose()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvtranspose#void%20cvTranspose%28const%20CvArr%2a%20src,%20CvArr%2a%20dst%29), which will rotate `rgbMat` 90 degrees, which is what you are attempting to do. This is possible because `rgbMat` is symmetric across both dimensions. This approach eliminates the need to explicitly iterate over each element of the `CvMat`.

```
cvTranspose(rgbMat, rgbMat);
```

Comment: +1 for identifying a potential case of overcomplicating the task